# The function $\exp(\frac{z-1}{z+1})$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, hardy-spaces

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. Consider the function $f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined as $f(z)=\exp(\frac{z-1}{z+1})$. Example 1.3.7 in page 21 of the book [Interpolation, Identification, and Sampling By Jonathan Richard Partington](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=zwjG1hXp15YC&pg=PA51&dq=disc%20algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo4Iad9YfSAhUQSo8KHX1tAukQ6AEIKzAC#v=snippet&q=by%20taking%20the%20harmonic%20extension&f=false)
 says the function $f$ belongs to the hardy space $H^{\infty}$ but not in the disc algebra $A(\bar D)$. Can any one tell why?
So basically

1. why is the function holomorphic on $D$?
2. why is it bounded on $D$?
3. Why is it not continuous on the boundary $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$.?

Comment: For (1); check that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Rieman equations and has continuous first partial derivatives. For (2), there is a theorem from complex analysis that says $f$ is either constant or unbounded on $D$. I don't know what to do for (3).

Comment: @Musse Redi: your arguments for (2) are not corrct: $f(z)=z$ is bonded on $D$ but not constant.

Comment: Something is not right: Consider a real $z=x$. As $x\to-1$ from above, $(1-x)/(1+x)$ approaches infinity, and hence so does the exponential.

Comment: @Fred You're right; my argument only works for $D= \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The function is holomorphic because it is the composition of holomorphic functions. Observe that the only singular point is $z=-1\notin D$.
2. The function $(z-1)/(1+z)$ is a Linear Fractional Transformation, also known as a Möbius function. It takes $D$ onto the left hand half-plane $H=\{z:\Re(z)<0\}$. The exponential function is bounded on $H$, because
   $$
   \bigl|e^{x+iy}\bigr|=e^x\le1\text{ if }x\le0.
   $$
3. If $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$, then
   $$
   \exp\Bigl(\frac{1-e^{i\theta}}{1+e^{i\theta}}\Bigr)=\cos\Bigl(\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\Bigr)-i\sin\Bigl(\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\Bigr).
   $$
   This function is not continuous at $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: I am sorry. It is (z-1)/(z+1). I have made the changes also. Can you tell how it follows now?